# How to retrieve a fragment that doesn't have a layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using a ListFragment that doesn't use a layout I created, and I need a way to set the fragment's ID so I can access it through an activity's getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByID(fragId) method.

In the onCreateView method of the fragment I'm trying to access, I did a setId(R.id.notes_fragment)  on the container being passed in. The id I set it to references the following code inside of res/values/ids.xml. Here's the content of ids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="notes_fragment" />
</resources>
```

But frag is null when I do this:

```
NotesFragment frag = (NotesFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.notes_fragment);
```

I used this to commit the fragment:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, notesFrag, NotesFragment.TAG).commit();

The docs say I can use the ID of this committed fragment to access it through findFragmentById. How can I get the ID of this committed fragment? I tried to pass the ID of the fragment I'm trying to access in the intent to start the activity (the one that needs to talk back to fragment), but it was null still.

Edit:

**I just found out about findFragmentByTag,** but even though I reference the fragment's TAG, it still comes back null even though the fragment is still hanging around.

Comment: how are you adding the ListFragment to your activity?  Is it defined in the activity's layout XML, or are you adding it later with a FragmentTransaction?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, notesFrag, NotesFragment.TAG).commit();

Comment: are you sure that the transaction has been executed before you try to get the fragment by its tag?  (e.g. is it visible on the screen?)